# Custom AuthorizeAttribute - Endpoint not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

I'm very new to Asp.net Core, i hope someone can help to find the problem.
I have Created a Custom `Authorize Attribute` to check login data stored in `appsettings.json`
The `Authorize Attribute` work (breakpoints hit, data correct).
But after the check, the requested endpoint never hit.

I have tested if the endpoint is work without `authorization`. And yes it's work.

In `Startup.cs` i load my Logins from `appsettings.json` and add it to the service as singleton.

```
LoginModel[] logins = Configuration.GetSection("LoginUsers").Get<LoginModel[]>();
Settings setting = new Settings();
setting.LoginModels = logins;
services.AddSingleton(setting);
```

My AuthorizeAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public MyAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // get username and password from header
        string authHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));
        int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');
        var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
        var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

        var services = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var settings = services.GetService<Settings>();

        var loginfound = settings.LoginModels.Where(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();


        if (loginfound == null)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[MyAuthorize]
public class SettingsController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("checkLogin")]
    public IActionResult CheckLogin()
    {

        return Ok(true);
    }
}
```

My endpoint is not work anymore. What am I doing wrong? I dont have any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using your own authorize logic with IAuthorizationFilter, you should not use with AuthorizeAttribute which will check the Authentication with default authentication schema.

Reference Tao Zhou's answer here:  [Asp.Net Core 2.1 - Authorize based on content in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854765/asp-net-core-2-1-authorize-based-on-content-in-request)